# how make this code dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have .wine-list-text-panel class for entire div and .wine-list-text for text. i applied jquery to first li but i want to repeat same jquery effect to all li .Instead of writing same code for different li with different classname. I want dynamic code which can apply to all li.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wine-list').mouseover(function() {
    $('.wine-list-text').hide();
    $('.wine-list-text-panel').css({
      "background": "#fff"
    });
  });

  $('.wine-list').mouseout(function() {
    $('.wine-list-text').show();
    $('.wine-list-text-panel').css({
      "background": "#000"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<section id="packages" class="">
  <div class="container demo-3">
    <!-- Top Navigation -->

    <ul class="grid cs-style-4">
      <li>
        <figure class="wine-list">
          <div class="wine-recommends">
            <img src="img/dummy.png" alt="img05">
          </div>
          <figcaption>
            <h5>Safari</h5>
            <span class="wine-recommends-text">Jacob Cummings</span>
            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116775-Safari" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Details</a>
          </figcaption>
          <div class="wine-list-text-panel" style="color: #fff;text-align: center;background: #000;padding: 5px 0;height: 30px;"><span class="wine-list-text">Chardonnay</span>
          </div>
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <div class="wine-recommends">
            <img src="img/dummy1.png" alt="img06">
          </div>
          <figcaption>
            <h5>Game Center</h5>
            <span class="wine-recommends-text">Jacob Cummings</span>
            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1118904-Game-Center">Details</a>
          </figcaption>
          <div class="wine-list-text-panel" style="color: #fff;text-align: center;background: #000;padding: 5px 0;height: 30px;"><span class="wine-list-text">Chardonnay</span>
          </div>
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <div class="wine-recommends">
            <img src="img/dummy.png" alt="img02">
          </div>
          <figcaption>
            <h5>Music</h5>
            <span class="wine-recommends-text">Jacob Cummings</span>
            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1115960-Music">Details</a>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <div class="wine-recommends">
            <img src="img/dummy.png" alt="img04">
          </div>
          <figcaption>
            <h5>Settings</h5>
            <span class="wine-recommends-text">Jacob Cummings</span>
            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1116685-Settings">Details</a>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <div class="wine-recommends">
            <img src="img/dummy.png" alt="img01">
          </div>
          <figcaption>
            <h5>Camera</h5>
            <span class="wine-recommends-text">Jacob Cummings</span>
            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1115632-Camera">Details</a>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
      <li>
        <figure>
          <div class="wine-recommends">
            <img src="img/dummy.png" alt="img03">
          </div>
          <figcaption>
            <h5>Phone</h5>
            <span class="wine-recommends-text">Jacob Cummings</span>
            <a href="http://dribbble.com/shots/1117308-Phone">Details</a>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hint: loop over each li element

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply some effect to all the div children of figure that are children of li (I guess so since .wine-list in your example is so), you can just do:

```
$('li > figure > div').mouseover( callbackWithHoverCode );
```

If those li elements are childs of, f.i. a '.example-list' ul, you can target them with:

```
$('.example-list li > figure > div').mouseover( callbackWithHoverCode );
```

However, is not clear if you just wanna do this or your issue is more complicated. In your question you talk about 'li with different classname', but in your code the li tags doesn't have classes and the class you're targeting with jQuery are those of the divs inside figure. If this answer doesn't help you, maybe you need to update your question and make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.wine-list').mouseover(function() {
      $(this).hide();
   }); 
});
```

and same thing for other elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You have to give some common class for generic items. like `<figure class="list-item wine-list">` `<div class="list-item-text-panel wine-list-text-panel">` `<span class="list-item-text wine-list-text">`

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $listItem = $('.list-item');
  var $listItemText;
  var $listItemTextPanel;
  var $this;


  $listItem.mouseover(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $listItemText = $this.find('.list-item-text');
    $listItemTextPanel = $this.find('.list-item-text-panel');
    $listItemText.hide();

    $listItemTextPanel.css({
      "background": "#fff"
    });
  });

  $listItem.mouseout(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $listItemText = $this.find('.list-item-text');
    $listItemTextPanel = $this.find('.list-item-text-panel');

    $listItemText.show();
    $listItemTextPanel.css({
      "background": "#000"
    });
  });
});
```

> Ref: http://jsbin.com/wixose/1/edit?html,js,output

You can try this code also:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $listItem = $('.list-item');
  var $listItemText;
  var $listItemTextPanel;
  var $this;

  $listItem.hover(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $listItemText = $this.find('.list-item-text');
    $listItemTextPanel = $this.find('.list-item-text-panel');
    $listItemText.hide();

    $listItemTextPanel.css({
      "background": "#fff"
    });
  }, function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $listItemText = $this.find('.list-item-text');
    $listItemTextPanel = $this.find('.list-item-text-panel');

    $listItemText.show();
    $listItemTextPanel.css({
      "background": "#000"
    });
  })
});
```